# Where to watch My Hero Academia: Two Heroes?

Tags: my-hero-academia

So I've been searching for a place to watch *My Hero Academia: Two Heroes* but I can't find any. If anyone has a link to a legal streaming site or knows where to watch it, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I believe there's no legal streaming of the movie yet. You'd probably have to look for the Blu-rays instead.

Comment: Oh ok i've even tried pirated streaming sights and had no luck

Comment: We don't condone illegal streaming here. But for the legal alternatives, you can keep an eye out over at [our list of legal streaming services](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-can-i-tell-if-a-site-is-legal/923#923) As it's not unlikely it will eventually turn up there.

Comment: I figured as much i'm just saying that its extremely hard to find. I always use stuff like crunchyroll and vrv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dimitrimx♦ mentioned, [there is no site which streams the movie legally yet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Hero_Academia:_Two_Heroes#Release) and as of now, I can't find any news as to when and where it will be possible to stream it online, if ever it will be made available online.

You can, however, opt for Blurays. I was able to find a subbed version on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07LDC9MR3) in case you're interested. Most likely they're also available in other online stores that sell Blurays, if you're looking for other options.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that. I prefer subbed anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently possible to stream this movie for free on Amazon Prime with a Starz subscription.  It is also possible to stream it after purchasing access via Amazon Prime, Vudu, Youtube, and Google Play.

This was likely not the case when this question was asked.